# aspectj not intercepting methods with annotation

Tags: java, aspectj

I am trying to get aspectj to intercept annotated methods:

```
@Aspect
    public class InterceptMeAspect {
      @Around("execution(* *(..)) && within(@InterceptMe *)")
      public Object doIntercept(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("intercepted:");
        return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
      }
    }

    public class InterceptedExample {
        @InterceptMe
        public void doSomething(){

        }
    }
```

I removed the !within(InterceptMeAspect) for brevity, but it isn't intercepting too much anyways.  If I remove the annotation constraint (within(@InterceptMe *)), it works, but intercepts everything and makes for a big problem.

The output bytecode appears to have the annotations intact, so I would expect the annotation criteria to match.  I am doing or attempting to do compile-time weaving.  This is important because I have another aspect that does work using the same approach above.  I suspect that aspect is messing with this one, but the final bytecode shouldn't have the annotation, right?

EDIT:
This is the code for the other aspect:

```
@Around(
      "execution(protected * *(..)) && !within(com.walterjwhite.logging..*) && !call(*.new(..)) && within(@ContextualLoggable *) && !within(@NonLoggable *)")
```

I have a generic logging aspect and a special contextual logging aspect.  I am guessing this is incorrectly written as well and should be following the format from above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `@Around("execution(* *(..)) && within(@InterceptMe *)")`.
It should be `@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(your.package.InterceptMe )")`

Or, if you need to access some properties from annotation:

```
@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(interceptMeVar)")
public Object doIntercept(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint,InterceptMe interceptMeVar)
```

Comment: Okay, I saw this approach on the documentation site as well, but why would the other aspect I have work?

Comment: @Walter Which one? Can you add it?

Comment: I added it to the end of the post - I think I should probably change it to match the example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

As you use a custom annotation, you should use @annotation instead of within:

```
@Aspect
    public class InterceptMeAspect {
      @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(com.or.org.package.InterceptMe)")
```

Comment: `@com.or.org.package.InterceptMe` need to be replaced with `com.or.org.package.InterceptMe`